# Used Directory.GetFiles to input files into array, but has its whole directory. I want it to only show the file name

Tags: c#

I am just beginning in C# helping collaborate on an inhouse application at work.

I currently have this code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    string filePath = @"C:\Whatever";
    string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);

        Console.WriteLine("-----Files:-----");
        foreach (string files in fileNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(files);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

How can I have the array list just the file name instead of the whole path to the file?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Path.GetFileName(fileName)` to get just the fiel name without the directory

```
// Will be an IEnumerable<string> not an string[]
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(filePath).Select(Path.GetFileName);
Console.WriteLine("-----Files:-----");
foreach (string files in fileNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(files);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Titian.